# When using Mockito with Kotlin how do you get around any() must not be null?

Tags: java, kotlin, mockito

While trying to mock up a function call getInventoryList(object, string, int, object, int) I found that I would continually encounter the error ArgumentMatchers.any() must not be null.

Here are some solutions I tried.
The MockitoHelper

```
object MockitoHelper {
fun <T> anyObject(): T {
    Mockito.any<T>()
    return uninitialized()
}
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
   fun <T> uninitialized(): T =  null as T
}
```

The any object deprecated function

```
ArgumentMatchers.anyObject()
```

The any(class : T)

```
ArgumentMatchers.any(Object::class.java)
```

None of the above worked for this particular problem.  Each of them came back with a similar must not be null error

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is the solution to the problem.  Tell Kotlin that if there is a null return to use an initialized version of the object.

```
ArgumentMatchers.any(Object::class.java) ?: Object()
```

This worked for my solution

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of rough edges when using mockito with Kotlin.

This small library takes care of the major ones: https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin

From the [wiki](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/wiki):

> Furthermore, Mockito returns null values for calls to method like any(), which can cause IllegalStateException when passing them to non-nullable parameters. This library solves that issue by trying to create actual instances to return.

[This is how they implement `any`](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/dbdef2fd74b86868a953e1ba609d235664148f50/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockitokotlin2/Matchers.kt#L43)

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> any(): T {
    return Mockito.any(T::class.java) ?: createInstance()
}
```

[createInstance() is implemented like this:](https://github.com/nhaarman/mockito-kotlin/blob/dbdef2fd74b86868a953e1ba609d235664148f50/mockito-kotlin/src/main/kotlin/com/nhaarman/mockitokotlin2/internal/CreateInstance.kt#L31)

```kotlin
inline fun <reified T : Any> createInstance(): T {
    return when (T::class) {
        Boolean::class -> false as T
        Byte::class -> 0.toByte() as T
        Char::class -> 0.toChar() as T
        Short::class -> 0.toShort() as T
        Int::class -> 0 as T
        Long::class -> 0L as T
        Float::class -> 0f as T
        Double::class -> 0.0 as T
        else -> createInstance(T::class)
    }
}

fun <T : Any> createInstance(kClass: KClass<T>): T {
    return castNull()
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this library doesn't work when the class has no default constructor.  At least this was my experience with it.